# pushViewController memory allocation problem

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, ios-simulator

I build an application and every tab-bar item contains 4 or sometimes 5 nested navigation..i try to do every thins BUT pushViewController cause a memory allocation problem in instruments and i don't know what can i do,,
the code is

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:table animated:YES];
[table release];
table=nil;
```

i try to print the reference count and i was shocked

the reference count before push is = 1
and after push is = 4

WHY??
can anyone help me please??

---

the code was i used to initiate the table is

```
custemTable *table=[[custemTable alloc] initWithNibName:@"custemTable" bundle:nil ];
 NSString selectedCellText=((custemCell)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]).THNameLabel.text;
 cll=(custemCell)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 cll.backgroundLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor ];
 [backgroundSelectedCell release];
 backgroundSelectedCell=nil;
 table.showingTill=selectedCellText;
 table.title=@"...";
 selectedCellText=nil;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:table animated:YES];
 [table release];
 table=nil;
```

the real problem that when the application starts the memory allocation be 1.56 M and when i select any cell and the pushViewController work the memory becaome 2.8 M and when i back the memory stay on range of 2.8 M (about 2.7 or 2.6 sometimes) to know..there are no memory leak and i was relese everything i allocate or retain or copy and i don't what can i do !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say there is something else in you App leaking that memory.

Can you paste more of your code, including how you are instantiating *table?

Also you shouldn't rely on the `retainCount` values to determine whether an object is leaking or not. The system will also retain objects that it needs and release it when they are no longer required, and your retainCount will always be affected by that.

As a general rule, if you alloc, retain or copy an object, it is your responsibility to release it. Everything else is dealt with by the system and will be flushed with the auto release pool.

Comment: Dear Rod..the code was i used to initiate the table is 

custemTable *table=[[custemTable alloc] ;initWithNibName:@"custemTable" bundle:nil ];
 NSString selectedCellText=((custemCell)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]).THNameLabel.text; cll=(custemCell)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; cll.backgroundLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor ]; [backgroundSelectedCell release]; backgroundSelectedCell=nil; table.showingTill=selectedCellText; table.title=@"..."; selectedCellText=nil; [self.navigationController pushViewController:table animated:YES];
 [table release];
[ table=nil;

Comment: There is no memory leak in that code. It could be that there is something else leaking memory inside your customTable instance.

Answer (score 0):

the code was i used to initiate the table is

custemTable *table=[[custemTable alloc] initWithNibName:@"custemTable" bundle:nil ]; 
NSString selectedCellText=((custemCell)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]).THNameLabel.text; cll=(custemCell)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; cll.backgroundLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor ]; [backgroundSelectedCell release]; backgroundSelectedCell=nil; table.showingTill=selectedCellText; table.title=@"...";
selectedCellText=nil;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:table animated:YES];
[table release]; 
table=nil;

the real problem that when the application starts the memory allocation be 1.56 M and when i select any cell and the pushViewController work the memory becaome 2.8 M
and when i back the memory stay on range of 2.8 M (about 2.7 or 2.6 sometimes)
to know..there are no memory leak and i was relese everything i allocate or retain or copy
and i don't what can i do !!!

Comment: Let the system take care of unloading the views and releasing memory when it needs. As long as you have your -dealloc and -viewDidUnload methods doing the right thing, that view will be deallocated and memory will be released as needed.

Comment: ya ya Rog.. i did everything to relese components and IBOutlets in -dealoc method and i asserted that he enter there..but i don't now why there still the same prob. !!